# `ls` with wildcard with subdirectories

Tags: command-line, 20.04, ls

When I execute a command `ls *`, it will show

1. files in the current directory
2. directories in the current directories
3. files and directories in the directories in the current directories.

When I do use `ls` I don't want to see inside the directories in the current directory. I'm bit confused because for more than 8 years I've been using ubuntu, I've never seen anything like this before.

Is this how `ls` should work? Is there a way to stop `3` from happening?

For example, if I have
file1.file
folder1
folder2
folder3
textfile1.txt

I want ls f* to show only

```
file1.file
folder1
folder2
folder3
```

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: `ls -l -d *` should do what you want.

Comment: +1 for Doug Smythies's tip, or even simpler (with only the names) `ls -d *` and `ls -d f*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting it to work like in MS-DOS, however, this is linux.

Wildcards in linux are expanded by your shell to match all items fitting the wildcards. `ls` does not see your wildcard. It only sees a list of file and directory names matching the wildcard. So it will show the contents of all items listed, i.e., the name of a file or the contents of a folder. In MS-DOS, wildcards would cause the `dir` command itself to filter the list to list only names fitting the wildcard.

To filter the output of  `ls`, e.g., to only see file and folder names  matching `f*`, use  `grep`, i.e., pipe the output of ls into grep like:

```
ls | grep ^f.*
```

`^` and `.*` are regular expressions. `^f` means: `f` but only at the very start. `.*` means `.` any character `*` any number of times.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't know why this was never an issue for me until now.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the `find` command instead of `ls`.  You can use `-maxdepth 1` so that you don't read into folders, and use only the `-name` option for wild cards.

Example:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name 'f*'
```

Will return everything in the current folder `.` starting with a lower case `f` even folder names, but not show you any contents within the folder(s).